# Can I set computed property in get block in Swift?

Tags: swift, computed-properties

```
var myProperty: PropertyType {
 get {
     if let alreadyComupted = savedValue {
       return alreadyComputed
     }
    return computeAndSave(someParam: "Hello")
 }
 set {
// is it possible to move *computeAndSave* body here somehow so I can call *set* method in above get definition?
 }
}

private var savedValue: PropertyType?
private func computeAndSave(someParam: SomeType) -> PropertyType {
// perform computations and assign value to *savedValue*
}
```

I am fairly new to swift language, not sure if this is even standard by coding practice or not.

Comment: Short answer is "yes", but, you would probably need a `fileprivate` property to which you store the result of the computation.  Then in `get`, you would return this property

Comment: ... but not if you want to be able to pass a value to your setter like you have with `computeAndSave`. In that case, you’d not have a `set` block (making your computed property effectively read-only) and just rely on `computeAndSave` to update your `savedValue`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you are describing a `lazy` variable. It calculates its initializer *once*, when the value is first fetched, and from then on uses the stored value (unless it is replaced). You can combine this with a define-and-call initializer:

```
lazy var myProperty: PropertyType = {
    let p = // perform some expensive one-time calculation here
    return p
}()
```

The outcome is that the *first* time you ask for the value of `myProperty`, the initializer method runs; but after that the previous result is used, and the initializer method never runs again.

Comment: One tiny issue to note with this solution is that lazy properties are not thread safe as of Swift 5.1. "If a property marked with the lazy modifier is accessed by multiple threads simultaneously and the property has not yet been initialized, there is no guarantee that the property will be initialized only once."